# Does running git clean have some type of permanent effect for future checkouts?

Tags: git

I have a very simple git repository that I've been using to learn git.  I have two branches in addition to `master`; `javafx`, `netty`.  I created a new project module within each branch.  For the `netty` branch, the project layout looks like this:

```
sandbox
  netty
```

For the `javafx` branch, the project layout looks like this:

```
sandbox
  javafx
```

Whenever I used to switch between branches, I would still have the directory from the other branch in my working directory.  I switched branches a lot and it the extra directory was never deleted.  I decided I should learn to clean up my working directory properly and, while on the `netty` branch, I ran:

```
git clean -fd
```

It did exactly what I expected, but now Git's checkout behavior seems different.  When I switch from the `netty` branch to the `javafx` branch it's just like it used to be; the extra `netty` directory stays in my working directory.  However, now when I switch from the `javafx` branch to the `netty` branch, the `javafx` directory gets deleted / cleaned automatically.

However, if I clone the repo on another machine it still works the way it used to; all the untracked files get left in my working directory.  Does `git clean -fd` have some type of permanent effect?

Edit: After some more playing, I have realized this has something to do with my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA).  Git can't seem to delete the directories of active project modules when I check out another branch that doesn't include those project modules.

For example, if I'm on my `netty` branch and checkout the `javafx` branch, Git can't seem to remove the `netty` directory.  However, if I re-check out the `netty` branch without regenerating my IDEA project, Git has no problem removing the `javafx` directory.

After my IDE prevents those directories from being deleted once, they hang around forever as untracked files in my local repo until I run `git clean -fd`.  Even closing my IDE and switching between branches doesn't change anything.

If I clone the repository and check out branches without ever starting my IDE, everything works like I would expect.  The unrelated directories are removed when I check out a new branch.

How does Git react if another process prevents it from removing an unneeded file when a new branch is checked out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page of git-help

> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not
>   under version control, starting from the current directory.
>
> Normally, only files unknown to git are removed, but if the -x option is specified, ignored files are also removed. This can, for example, be useful to remove all build products.
>
> If any optional ... arguments are given, only those paths are affected.

In essence **git clean -fd** removes all untracked files and directories in your local copy except for the files ignored in .gitignore.

My suspicion is you have started tracking those generated files by mistake in one of those branches.

Comment: The show up as untracked when I run `git status`.  I got more time to play with it and it has something to do with my IDE.  I'll edit the question to provide more info.

Comment: I have decided to accept this answer because it technically answers the question; the documentation makes it clear that git clean does not have a permanent effect.  As a side note, I haven't had this problem since I started making sure my .gitignore file is set up properly.

Comment: +1 because I was unaware of `git clean`; I have been typing `git ls-files -i -o -x \* | xargs rm` over and over again.